# Using Laravel schema builder and migrations

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am new to Laravel PHP framework. I am confused with how Laravel schema builder and migrations work. I created two tables using Laravel migrations. Below are my two tables:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('hotels', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('hotel_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('province')->nullable();
            $table->string('country')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This is my other table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('rooms', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('hotel_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My question is how can can I make relations with two tables using Foreign keys? If I have to use Schema Builder where do I have to put the schema file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the very same migrations, using Schema Builder. This is how you create a foreign key using migrations:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('rooms', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('hotel_id');

        $table->string('name');

        $table->foreign('hotel_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('hotels')
              ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: I am tried use your way. I am getting this errors:  [Exception]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'hotel_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `rooms` add constraint rooms_hotel_id_foreign foreign key
   (`hotel_id`) references `hotels` (`id`) on delete cascade) (Bindings: array (
  ))

Comment: so I have to create the column first then add the foreign key ?

Comment: Yes, but you can make it in the same migration. The foreign key is just a constraint + index.